# I can connect to an FTP server with PHP but can't ftp_nlist even with passive mode

Tags: php, ftp

I have a problem. I can connect to a FTP server, but I can't use `ftp_nlist`. The page is white and loading endlessly.

Here's my code :

```
$ftpStream = ftp_connect($host,$port);

if($ftpStream!=false)
{
    echo 'FTP Connected </br>';
    echo 'Hostname = ' . $host . '</br>';
    $login=ftp_login($ftpStream,$username,$password);
    if($login!=false)
    {
        echo 'Logged in </br>';
        $pasvMode = ftp_pasv($ftpStream, true);
        if($pasvMode!=false)
        {
            echo 'Entered passive mode </br>';
            // These lines aren't working:
            $listOfFiles = ftp_nlist($ftpStream,'.');
            var_dump($listOfFiles);
        }

        else
            echo 'ftp_pasv() fail </br>';
    }
    else
        echo 'Login failure </br>';
}
else
    echo 'ftp_connect fail </br>';
```

When I'm only trying to connect to this server, everything works well, but when I'm trying to `ftp_nlist`, nothing works. When I try this code on another FTP server, the list of files is correctly displayed. I don't really know from where the problem could come.

I tried to connect to FTP from command-line on the web server and here are the results:

```
ftp> ls
Command okay.
150 File status okay; about to open data connection
```

Here's the FileZilla log file, when connecting from my local machine:

```
2018-05-22 15:45:03 5180 1 Réponse : 230 User logged in, proceed.
2018-05-22 15:45:03 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:03 5180 1 Commande : USER Username@IPADRESS:PORT
2018-05-22 15:45:04 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:04 5180 1 Réponse : 331 User name okay, need password.
2018-05-22 15:45:04 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:04 5180 1 Commande : PASS ****
2018-05-22 15:45:08 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:08 5180 1 Réponse : 230 User logged in, proceed.
2018-05-22 15:45:08 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:08 5180 1 Commande : SYST
2018-05-22 15:45:09 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:09 5180 1 Réponse : 215 Windows_CE version 6.0.
2018-05-22 15:45:09 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:09 5180 1 Commande : FEAT
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Réponse : 211-Features:
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Réponse :   SIZE
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Réponse : 211 End
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Statut : Le serveur ne supporte pas les 
caractères non-ASCII.
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Statut : Connecté 
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : Measured latency of 1145 ms
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Statut : Récupération du contenu du dossier...
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ChangeDirSend()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Commande : PWD
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Réponse : 257 "/"
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : 
CFtpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2018-05-22 15:45:10 5180 1 Commande : TYPE I
2018-05-22 15:45:11 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:11 5180 1 Réponse : 200 Command okay.
2018-05-22 15:45:11 5180 1 Suivi : 
CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2018-05-22 15:45:11 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:11 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2018-05-22 15:45:11 5180 1 Commande : PASV
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Réponse : 227 Entering Passive Mode 
(10,64,3,53,12,188)
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Suivi : 
CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Commande : LIST
2018-05-22 15:45:12 5180 1 Suivi : CTransferSocket::OnConnect
2018-05-22 15:45:13 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:13 5180 1 Réponse : 150 File status okay; about to open 
data connection.
2018-05-22 15:45:13 5180 1 Suivi : 
CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2018-05-22 15:45:13 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2018-05-22 15:45:13 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Réponse : 226 Closing data connection. 
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : 
CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : 
CFtpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2018-05-22 15:45:15 5180 1 Statut : Contenu du dossier affiché avec succès
```

Is it possible for a server to forbid ftp_nlist() ?

Sorry for my bad English, and thanks in advance for your future answers.

Comment: Did you sort out the problem? I'M struggling with the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web hosting provider blocks outgoing data connections to the FTP server.

You can try using an active mode (remove the `ftp_pasv` call). But it's quite unlikely that they would allow incoming connections (needed for the active mode), if they forbid outgoing connections.

For some background, see my article about [network setup needed for passive and active FTP modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) - Though nothing you can do about it yourself. You need to contact your provider.

Comment: But is it possible that my WAMP also blocks these sames data connections ?

Comment: I do not know what WAMP you mean - You never mentioned any.

Comment: I also tried to connect to this FTP server without using my hosted website, with this WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/ -> Apache2, PHP, MySQL), and the result is the same

Comment: Can you use Wireshark (or any other tool) to capture FTP traffic of the PHP script running on WAMP?

Comment: I'll be downloading all the required stuff and learn how to use it properly, so you don't lose your time, I'll edit my post as soon as possible. I'll mention your name when it will be done, thank you.

Comment: @MartinPrikyl I captured the traffic, and nothing was displayed when I filtered with tcp.port==21 || tcp.port==20

Comment: Maybe you were not capturing the correct network interface. Make sure you capture everything.

Comment: I tried again with 2 different FTP servers (one was working with my PHP code, and the other doesn't). I can't catch anything from the one where I have connection issues, but the other gives me "normal" results (username, password, passive mode...) @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I do not know how to help you with that. I makes little sense, as you are able to connect, so there should be some traffic visible.

Comment: I think that I will give up and use another solution

Comment: Did you sort out the problem? I'M struggling with the same problem now for 8 hours...

Comment: @WojtekB So contact your provider, as my answer says.